# Saving values from php $_SESSION through $_POST in form inputs with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, session

How to add ajax sent data in form inputs to be saved as session. I have session_start() in header.php. I'm saving the code in the database and it works. Thanks.
I tried this:

**HTML form**

```
<form action='' method='post'>
  <input id='code' type='text' name='code'>
  <a id='send_code'>Send code</a>
</form>
```

**AJAX** (I have a submit handler for this)

```
var code = $('#code').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {action: 'insert_code', code: code},
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

**PHP from functions.php**

```php
$code = ( isset( $_POST['code'] ) ) ? htmlspecialchars( trim( $_POST['code'] ) ) : '';
$_SESSION['contest'] = array(
    'code'  => $code,
);

if( isset( $_SESSION['contest']) ){
    echo 'Session: ' . $_SESSION['contest']['code'];
}else{
    echo "Session not set";
}
```

Comment: does the developer console (F12 in most browsers) report any errors? also look at the network-tab of your console - what is the response you get to your ajax request?

Comment: In console i get "Session: 4123423" (the code)

Comment: You have not closed the `a` tag so perhaps most likely the ajax function is not being registered correctly

Comment: Sorry for that. I have a much bigger code. All the code from here is shortened for readability and speed purposes. In my original code that is ok. I modified in my question too.

Comment: and where do you check if your session-variable is set?

Comment: in functions.php in the code above.

Comment: yes, but at this point it seems to work - like you told me. at which point is the session var not set? at which point in the code do you have problems?

Comment: at how to get that session value in my input value and stay there after page refresh.

Comment: Try to also put a session_start() in the functions.php code. Maybe because it is a separate request the session is not shared?

Comment: Thanks man. That was the problem. I had the session_start() function in header.php. You should post that as the answer to accept it. Also, can you please explain to me why that worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Why? That's the default.